# could not put the numbers in the middle of the bar chart next to the histogram

Tags: r

I was inspired by one of the codes here in stackoverflow and  create a histogram and a barchart next to each other. My code is this

```
risk <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Age = c("0-19", "20-39", "40-65", "65+"),
  obesityrisk = c(0.5567, 0.1004, 0.3691, 0.4526)
)

obesity <- data.frame(  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Age = c("0-19", "20-39", "40-65", "65+"),
  n = c(3567, 6004, 8691, 9966)
)
 
d1 <- ggplot(obesity, aes(x=Age, y=n)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")  + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE)) 
 
 d2 <- risk %>% 
  mutate(
    Age = fct_rev(factor(Age))
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Age, obesityrisk)) +
  geom_col(fill = colorspace::lighten("gray"), width = 0.7) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs( x = NULL, y = NULL, 
        title = "relative \nobesity rate\nby Age") +
  geom_text(aes(Age, obesityrisk, label = paste0(obesityrisk, "%")), 
            size = 2.5, hjust = 1) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 9, angle = 90, hjust = 0.5),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(color = colorspace::lighten("black", amount = 0.5))
  )
 
 layout <- "
AAAA##
AAAABB
"

d1 + d2  + plot_layout(design = layout, heights = c(1, 30)) +
  plot_annotation(
    title = "Absolute numbers of Obesity by Age in Ireland"
  )
```

The problem is that the numbers in % are were bad positioned. I want  to have it in the middle of the bar chart.
How can I fix it, that the numbers are in the middle of the bar chart? The problem is the left side.

I think if someone run the code it is visible  the problem. Hopefully

If not please let me know that I can describe  it more understandable

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To place the labels in the middle of the bars use `position_stack(vjust = .5)` and set `hjust=.5`. Also, to format as percentages I used `scales::percent` which will scale you values by default by 100 (not sure whether that is correct as I don't know your data).

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(forcats)

d1 <- ggplot(obesity, aes(x=Age, y=n)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")  + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE)) 

d2 <- risk %>% 
  mutate(
    Age = fct_rev(factor(Age))
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Age, obesityrisk)) +
  geom_col(fill = colorspace::lighten("gray"), width = 0.7) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs( x = NULL, y = NULL, 
        title = "relative \nobesity rate\nby Age") +
  geom_text(aes(Age, obesityrisk, label = scales::percent(obesityrisk)), 
            size = 2.5, hjust = .5, 
            position = position_stack(vjust = .5)
            ) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 9, angle = 90, hjust = 0.5),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(color = colorspace::lighten("black", amount = 0.5))
  )

layout <- "
AAAA##
AAAABB
"

d1 + d2  + plot_layout(design = layout, heights = c(1, 30)) +
  plot_annotation(
    title = "Absolute numbers of Obesity by Age in Ireland"
  )
```

[image]